# Swift: cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController!'

Tags: swift, admob, interstitial

I am trying to load an admob interstitial ad in my app when the users lost but i can't because i am using spritekit (swift), here's my code:

```
 self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(interstitial)
```

and here's my error:

```
cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController!'
```

Hope one of you has the answer! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to present `interstitial` from itself.

You should present it from a ViewController which is currently visible:

```
self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
```

(supposed that `self` is a View Controller).

**Update:**

If you follow Google [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial) **attentively**, you will see there exactly what I'm talking about:

```
func gameOver() {
  if self.interstitial.isReady {
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
  }
  // Rest of game over logic goes here.
}
```

Comment: Paste a link here. You made a mistake and voting me down, man.

Comment: The problem with that tutorial is everything is done on in the same file, the GameViewController.swift --- but in most games, while there is still the gameviewcontroller, there are multiple other fiels/skscenes like a gameover.swift, which is usually where you want to call the add.  I'm having some trouble with it as well -- no idea why interstital ads have to be such a challenge, and usually once I get it down, xcode or swift decides to update ... derp