# SpriteKit and GoogleAdMobs interstitial

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am trying to load this google interstitial ad when the game is over.

```
 if (self.interstitial.isReady)
        {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
```

But I am getting an error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController!".
I have used the same lines of code with my other apps that don't use sprite kit, is it different with sprite kit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController!'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692755/swift-cannot-convert-value-of-type-gamescene-to-expected-argument-type-uivie)

Comment: @SashaKozachuk that same answer didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's different in SpriteKit because you trying to present from a SKScene and not a UIViewController.

Try this and see if it works

```
if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
     self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self.view?.window?.rootViewController)
}
```

If you are getting a nil crash now than you did not init the ad property correctly. You should also have some checks to ensure this does not happen.

This is how the adMob code from my gitHub helper looks.

You should have a property like so

```
 var interstitial: GADInterstitial?
```

Than in view didLoad you should preload the ad

```
  interstitial = adMobLoadInterAd()
```

This is pre-loading code.

```
  func adMobLoadInterAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    Debug.print("AdMob inter loading...")

    let googleInterAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "Your adMob ID")
    googleInterAd.delegate = self

    let request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID] // DEBUG only

    googleInterAd.loadRequest(request)

    return googleInterAd
}
```

Than when you want to show an ad you call this

```
func adMobShowInterAd() {
    guard interstitial != nil && interstitial!.isReady else { // calls interDidReceiveAd
        Debug.print("AdMob inter is not ready, reloading")
        interstitial = adMobLoadInterAd()
        return
    }

    Debug.print("AdMob inter showing...")
    interstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self.view?.window?.rootViewController)
}
```

Than finally in the delegate methods you should pre load a new ad when the current ad is dismissed.

```
 func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    Debug.print("AdMob inter closed")
    interstitial  = adMobLoadInterAd()
}
```

Comment: Right in your code spot. Just replace the second line with this. See updated answer.

Comment: I got a helper on gitHib as well  if you are looking for a nice and clean solution. https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

Comment: I have put ads on my other apps before but not a game. It doesnt seem to be working in sprite kit

Comment: It says found nil in debugger

Comment: On what line? You than didnt load the intertestial add correctly if you get a nil crash. I guess because on regular app you are creating the banner in storyBoard you might not have init it properly in spritekit.

Comment: Ill update my answer with some code examples from my helper.

Comment: Where do I put that code in GameViewController or GameScene? because I need to load it in game scene when the game ends. But in game scene I can load the inertial is ready code.

Comment: Well if your code is in the gameScene than put it in gameScene.

Comment: but thats the problem its crashing in gameScene

Comment: Not if you are using my code. You are not loading the ad correctly in your code  which is why you get a nil crash. You are also not having a check to make sure the ad is not nil before trying to show it.

Comment: it doesn't work and I am not following the logic. How do I load my GADInterstitial in my game scene?

Comment: I have step by step instructions in my answer. What are you struggling with?